# Searching for images is buggy

Tags: bug, search, images

The Advanced Search Options say we could use

> [url "*.example.com"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10739/19341)

Further the tooltip says: "Find images and links in posts". But when I do the search, I get [only 284 results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com). When I search for my images I only get [one result](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22i.stack.imgur.com%22+user%3A19341) and I know that this can't be true.

What did I do wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I noticed this same thing. I know I used to search for images in my posts this way sometime in the past, but it has been broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source of the sole result you found with search, I see that one of the image URLs is included as a **link** `[text](url)`, not as embedded image `![text](url)` or `[index]: url`. Apparently, the url search ignores all embedded images. Yes, looks like a bug. (If this is by design, it's a bug-by-design.)

There's a workaround until SE fixes the bug: the query [posted here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9402/) finds 29 of your posts with images.

Comment: In this answer, I included the link to  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9402/ in `[1]: ...` format. The URL search does not see it.

Comment: Almost all of my images use the `![description](url)` format. Only recently have I been using the `[index]: url` format. I try `user:13854 "*.png"` and get no results. Same with `user:13854 url:"*i.stack.imgur.com"`

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for another data point. In the post by draks that shows up in the search, there is no `!` in front: it's a regular hyperlink, not an embedded image. It seems the url search ignores images embedded in any way. As for the search `user:13854 "*.png"`, it does not succeed by design: markup is ignored by regular search.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that a year or so ago, I used that search to find all images in my posts. I hope that capability will be restored.

Comment: @robjohn They changed the search engine a while ago: see [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76914/).

Comment: Thanks for the links...